# Non-printing characters in Word 2011 not showing even when enabled

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2011

I have a document I work on often, my resume. I have created a few different styles that I use and for some reason the non-printing characters have stopped showing properly. I have the option enabled (the reversed P) and ensured "All" characters are selected in the preferences. Here is a screenshot of the current view:

[image: SS1]

basically, only the tab stops and the returns are showing.

Upon doing an experiment by creating a new document, all characters (especially the spaces) show up nicely:

[image: SS2]

I can copy this line and paste it into my resume document and it shows up there too. It seems my styles are doing something...

Comment: Thanks, edited the question now. All characters are enabled in the preferences.

Comment: please explain what you mean.

Comment: no I do not have any white on white characters.